# Does an OGL Version of D6-Legend exist?

Tags: ogl, d6-system

I'm wondering. I saw a few references that aside from the normal D6 also D6 legend could be OGL. (d6that is success based and 5+ is a success).

When I searched I stumbled only over one single book there that didn't seem very official and deviated greatly from d6 legend as it had 3+ as a success.

So my question is: is there a OGL variant of d6 legend?

Answer (score 1):

Since 2009 there is an OGL version of the D6 system known as [Open D6](http://www.sycarion.com/open-d6-pdfs/).

Comment: I know still though d6 Legend is a subvariant of D6 from what I saw in the open d6 it is "Just" the normal d6 rules (aka xd6 add the results together and not like in legend  xd6 and every 5+ is a success). thus the question (can be that I'm overlookigng something within the d6 books ht ewhole time if that is the case then would be good to know and in which book that variant is mentioned.